# Click on export link and check status code and file export or not?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-6, laravel-dusk

Pleas any one help me I have spend too much time but no luck.

When I perform test case for `Export CSV` file. I'm getting error as on below:

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Browser\LoginTest::test_export_qp_list
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnexpectedJavascriptException: javascript error: Ca
nnot read property 'click' of undefined
  (Session info: headless chrome=79.0.3945.88)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f
143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)

E:\Portal Files\Laravel-Practise\Dusk Test Cases\Dusk\dusk-query-pages\vendor\fa
cebook\webdriver\lib\Exception\WebDriverException.php:122
E:\Portal Files\Laravel-Practise\Dusk Test Cases\Dusk\dusk-query-pages\vendor\fa
cebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.php:331
```

1. I have export link with blade code is:

```
    <a id="export" class="btn btn-outline-primary pull-right text-capitalize mr-2" href="{{url('/qp-export')}}">
        <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i>
        Export CSV
    </a>`
```

2. And route of this link is:

   ```
   Route::get('qp-export', 'HomeController@qpExport')->name('qpExport');
   ```
3. Laravel dusk test case code is:

   ```
   $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
              $browser->visit('/home')
              ->clickLink('#export')
              ->assertStatus(200);
   });
   ```

Comment: @ Ijaz Ali  write your error's message in the post,  don't upload error's image.

Comment: #iraj jelodari please check i have added error above. please check

Comment: An error usually comes with a screenshot. Check to see if the link available and visible at the time the error occurs

Comment: #apokryfos yes i have checked Link is available at this time. But when click on `export csv` link then error is showing.